# How do I wait until text of element changes to something else than a string?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium with Python 3 to retrieve the contents from an element on a webpage. There is an element with dynamic text.

```
<div id="accResp">Please wait...</div>
```

The "Please wait..." section changes to different strings like "**Password Incorrect**", "**Loading**".

How do I wait until the string changes to anything except "**Please wait...**"?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your functionality you will see text in your web page so you can handle text using below xpath's:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

**password Incorrect**

```
passwordIncorrect = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Password Incorrect')]")))
```

**Loading**

```
 loading = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Loading')]")))
```

**Please wait...**

```
waitText= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Please wait...')]")))
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```